# Pinvoke error on opening serial (USB) port

Tags: silverlight, serial-port, usb, pinvoke

I am using a Serial Wrapper written by someone else with PInvoke (I do not know much about this)

The Serial Wrapper is used in a Silverlight Web App to access a USB device through a serial com port

This application has been working for a long time but have the odd occurence where we cannot get the app to work and the Serial Wrapper fails on opening the COM port when calling the following "CreateFile" Method:

```
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
    static extern IntPtr CreateFile(string fileName,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileAccess fileAccess,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileShare fileShare,
       IntPtr securityAttributes,
       [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.U4)] FileMode creationDisposition,
       int flags,
       IntPtr template);
```

These are the parameters I am sending to this method:

```
CreateFile(COM12, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero)
```

This seems to return the IntPtr as -1 instead of something greater than IntPtr.Zero, but as I said is only happening on very few PCs and so far the only patern I have been able to find seems to be HP machines with Windows 7 64bit SP1

Added the following code from the suggestion by Hans:

```
            Log lg = new Log();
        lg.write("Opening Serial Port - CreateFile(this.PortName, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero)");
        lg.write("PARAMETERS - CreateFile(" + this.sPortName.ToString()+ ", FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None, IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero)");
        pHandle = CreateFile(this.sPortName, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.None,
            IntPtr.Zero, FileMode.Open, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
        if (pHandle == IntPtr.Zero || pHandle == new IntPtr(-1))
        {
            int ErrorCode = Marshal.GetLastWin32Error();
            if (pHandle == IntPtr.Zero)
            {
                lg.write("Open Serial Port Failed: CreateFile (pHandle == IntPtr.Zero)");
                lg.write("LastWin32Error = " + ErrorCode.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                lg.write("Open Serial Port Failed: CreateFile (pHandle == IntPtr(-1))");
                lg.write("LastWin32Error = " + ErrorCode.ToString());
            }
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            lg.write("Open Serial Port Success");
        }
```

Comment: Error checking is the usual victim of this kind of pinvoke.  It is never optional, you don't get the friendly .NET exceptions to keep you out of trouble and tell you what went wrong.  So you just don't know what went wrong, nor do we.  You must add it.

Comment: @HansPassant As I don't really understand the PInvoke stuff, do you have any suggestion on what type of error checking I could add to this function to give me something to work with - I have put error loggin in to narrow it down to this point of failure, but don't know how to norrow it down further. I can include to entire Serial Wrapper code for someone, if this could help???

Comment: You have to check the return value, if it equals new IntPtr(-1) then it failed.  You'd normally immediately throw new System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception() but this is Silverlight, it probably doesn't exist.   Can't help you if you don't mention the version number.  Marshal.GetLastWin32Error() is the fallback.

Comment: @HansPassant Thank you, this at least gives me hope to find what is causing the random failures... Please see edit to question for how I implemented your suggestion, does that seem Okay?

Comment: It doesn't return IntPtr.Zero, just don't add random code.